# What is the correct way of passing S3 headers inside Django?

Tags: python, django, encryption, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using `S3BotoStorage` as my `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` in my django app. So all the files that I upload to my app are uploaded to a S3 bucket. 
I wanted to encrypt my files using SSE-C so I following the documentation provided [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html) by AWS. I added the following lines to my `settings.py`

```
# settings.py
AWS_S3_ENCRYPTION = True
key = ...
key_md5 = ...
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm': 'AES256',
    'x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key': key,
    'x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5': key_md5,
}
```

But as soon as I add these headers I start receiving the following error.

```
[Error 104] Connection Reset by Peer
```

The file uploads are working fine without the headers.

I don't why is this happening?

Please let me know if anymore details are needed.

Comment: Since you are using a third party call to the API, you should check and make use of the codebase argument, because it will override and ignore stuff it doesn't understand.   And searching for "encrypt" in the source : 
https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto.py , it seems you just need to enable a parameter .

Comment: @mootmoot Thanks for pointing that out but I've already enabled that parameter that you are talking about. I've updated the question description.

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to use your OWN encryption key or using S3 encryption?

Comment: I want to use S3's Server Side Encryption using Customer Provided Encryption Keys (SSE-C) Mechanism. Here is the link to documentation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html

Comment: A quick glance on boto2 S3 API (that S3BotoStorage is using), it doesn't support custom encryption. You may need to patch S3BotoStorage or write your own code to use boto3 that support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: the wrapper you are using doesn't support custom encryption key, due to obsoleted boto2 implementation.

Long answer : 
Here is the source of [S3BotoStorage](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=S3BotoStorage). Now here come the puzzle of [how boto2 saving file](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html). Where did you find the header? So I see they suggest something like this

```
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Expires': 'Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400',
}
```

There is no example for encryption headers passing to boto. The header you given, is for REST API, not the S3BotoStorage wrapper.  So you may only able to use this and forget about setting the AWS_HEADERS for the encryption algorithm, give custom encryption key.

And the confusing part is , in boto2, S3 object name are call key (in boto3, they improve it and call it key_name explicitly) . This has nothing to do with encryption key.